# Human full body detection: contour rather than rectangle

Tags: opencv

I have to implement a contour detection of full human body (from feet to head, in several poses such as raising hands etc.) using opencv. I managed to compile and run code I found here https://gist.github.com/yoggy/1470956, but it only draws a rectangle around the body, and not the exact contour. Can one help me with identifying and displaying the contour itself?

Thanks!!

Comment: same is true for peopledetect opencv sample, which draws rectangles only

Answer (score 6):

I'm afraid the answer to this question is:

**There's no algorithm that can do this perfectly.**

Computer vision has not developed to that extent yet. Take a look at recent papers in CVPR, PAMI, and you will find that most algorithms are "rectangle", or more specifically, bounding-box based, in terms of human labeling and algorithmic detecting.

It is true that you can find the contours within the bounding-box. However the computer just doesn't know which contour belongs to the specified object.

I suggest you search for "human pose estimation" for further information.

Comment: I agree. Not sure my boss will ;) Anyway I have to do it as reasonably currently possible

Comment: Talk to your boss. His trying to invent the next century.

Comment: I meant, it doesn't have to be accurate, and I did see one old project (without opencv) that implements this roughly.

Comment: have you found any solutions?

Answer (score 5):

One approach that might work is background subtraction:

http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/db/d5c/tutorial_py_bg_subtraction.html

This would work for video but perhaps also for single images in a scenario where you were in a controlled (fixed camera) environment where you had an image of the pose and also and image of the background, with no one present.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function findCountors within the returned bounding box:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/shapedescriptors/find_contours/find_contours.html

Comment: thanks much! it looks like what I need. I unsuccessfully tried to put it in the code above, can you please guide me how to actually see it? assume threshold is constant. or preferrably into peopledetect.cpp opencv sample. thanks again

Comment: I'm not sure as I do not have much experience with that code.