# Human body detection using OpenCV in Android

Tags: opencv, android

I want to create an Android application in which i want to detect human body from an image. I haven't started coding yet(its just an idea), so i am not able to show you any codes. I heard about OpenCV face detection for android.
I have tried to use OpenCV face detection, But since i am newbie in android, i am not able to do so.

My question is "Is there anything in OpenCV that can help me to detect whole human body rather than just face?", if YES then "is there any tutorials regarding this?"

thanks for HELP in advance.

Comment: There are some other stackoverflow questions on this subject; they might be useful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871294 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336434 and probably others; those were just the ones that popped up at the top of a google search (which you'd be well advised to do!)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to detect the human body in the form of images or videos using `OpenCV`, follow the steps below in order to start:

**Step1**

Create a new OpenCV project in Android Studio. In [this](http://blog.codeonion.com/2015/11/25/creating-a-new-opencv-project-in-android-studio/) tutorial, it explains how to create a new OpenCV project in Android Studio.

**Step2**

The following links explain Human detection using OpenCV:

- [HOG Person Detector Tutorial](http://mccormickml.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/)
- [People Detection in OpenCV](http://www.magicandlove.com/blog/2011/08/26/people-detection-in-opencv-again/)

Comment: Thank you for this help, I will go through this tutorials, I hope it works.

Comment: @MuhammadYounas I do agree your links are most effective. But its always good to include sample code . As links may get obsolete. By the way I have upvoted your answer as well

Comment: I do one project from those links and it is working i detect crosswalking using opencv